# Oracle query to JPA query conversion

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to covert the following oracle query to JPA

```
Select o.parent_id,o.group_id,
       (
         Select count(*) 
           From x_group g 
          Where g.parent_id=o.group_id
        ) 
 From x_group o 
Where o.parent_id='ABC'
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just do it and try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JPA specifications (I checked both v1 & 2.0), it is not possible. In section 4.6.16 (JPA 2.0 Specification) it states:

> Subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause.[58]

So you might consider using native queries for this case, or rewriting your query.

Comment: Hibernate supports them in the select clause, though. And the question is tagged Hibernate.

Comment: Even though Hibernate supports it, it is not supported by JPA as an abstraction layer, at least according to specification. However, it might still work out when using Hibernate as a JPA provider (as a JPQL query), but that's gonna be a small step away from JPA specification.